# How to iteratively build a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

I had a hypothetical question for you, so excuse the code. This question regards a past test that I took, and an answer that I couldn't figure out, so it's not "doing homework," just something to satisfy my own curiosity. Unfortunately, I did not save any of my code.

Let's suppose we have the following input:

```js
const input = [
                 ["add", "Hello"],
                 ["add", ", how"],
                 ["add", "is it"],
                 ["add", "going today?"]
              ]
```

How would one go about getting the following output:

```js
["Hello",
 "Hello, how",
 "Hello, how is it",
 "Hello, how is it going today?"]
```

I utilized an output array (`output`), looped through `input`, and on each iteration I pushed `input[0][1]` to `output`, and to no surprise I built up an array that's just `input[0][i]`. Very rough example:

```js
const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++ {
    output.push(input[0][i];
}
=> ["Hello", ", how", "is it", "going today?"]
```

I had a few thoughts about how to go, but unfortunately ran out of time. One thought was just to iterate through the 'output' array and try to += a string, and then loop over that string (while it's being built) pushing to a final array. The other way was some sort of string builder, which I couldn't figure out.

Apologies if this is simple, I'm still learning.

Comment: In your example did you mean `Hello, how is it going today?`? You said `Hello, how is it going?`

Comment: My colleague @nick-schmitt pointed out that having a previous or last variable, that would point back to whatever is in the previous output, and add the iterated element to that, would work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I hopefully fixed my typo. Obviously I need more coffee lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple loop and push string at each iteration

```js
const input = [
  ["add", "Hello"],
  ["add", ", how"],
  ["add", "is it"],
  ["add", "going today?"]
]

function addStr(arr){
  let newArr = []
  let str = ""
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    str = str + arr[i][1]
    newArr.push(str)
  }
  return newArr
}

console.log(addStr(input))
```

Answer (score 3):

Uses `Array.reduce`, then slice the array based on current index of `input`, finally `join` the slices.

```js
const input = [
                 ["add", "Hello"],
                 ["add", ", how"],
                 ["add", "is it"],
                 ["add", "going today?"]
              ]
console.log(
  input.reduce((pre, cur, index, itself) => {
    pre[index] = itself.slice(0, index + 1).map(item => item[1]).join(' ')
    // pre[index] = itself.slice(0, index + 1).filter(item => item[0] === 'add').map(item => item[1]).join(' ') // if assuming only join the action (verb) is 'add'
    return pre
  }, [])
)
```

Comment: I really need to learn reduce better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer using `reduce`, but a different implementation that I tend to prefer because it's a bit easier to debug IMO:

```
const input = [
  ["add", "Hello"],
  ["add", ", how"],
  ["add", "is it"],
  ["add", "going today?"]
]

input.map(([_first, second]) => second)
  .reduce(
    (agg, newStr) => ([
      ...agg,
      (agg[agg.length - 1] + " " + newStr).trim()
    ]),
    [""]
  )
  .slice(1)
```

This gets you pretty close, but only caveat is that there's an oddity where you don't have a space between `Hello` and `", how"` which is a bit difficult to reconcile programatically.